# What do repeating '^@' symbols in a logfile mean?

Tags: linux, debian, log-files

A few times I have come across this in a log file:

```
Sep 17 09:35:57 00187d378926 ovpn-00187d378926[1701]: /sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
Sep 17 09:35:57 00187d378926 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Sep 17 09:35:57 00187d378926 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.4" x-pid="1707" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

What does it mean?  Sometimes it is a single line, other times it is lots of lines.  I usually see it happen on Debian 6 machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that these are NULL (0x00) characters.  Just from the segment of the log file that you have presented, looks like a reboot.  It is possible that the buffer to be written out to the logfile was a little corrupt due to the stopping of the kernel logging daemon while attempting to write out something.  This is only an educated guess however.

Summary: I'd not be overly converned from what I see here.